# Field values in sObject data retrieved in LwC javascript cannot be accessed in Salesforce screen flow, field values

Tags: salesforce

your text I am required to send the record Id of an sObject available from a lookup input in a   Salesforce scren flow to a LwC component , retrieve the record from the User object , extract the Name, MobilePhone and Email field values from the record and send back to the screen flow for displaying , using those to default other fields on the same screen from where the LwC call is invoked. I used the below LwC script. As can be seen in the javascript file I used the lrecordId input property to access the User Id from the screen flow and feed to the LwC. I need to extract the Name,Phone,Email values from the matching User record and send back to the flow for displaying and using to default text input fields on the same screen in the flow. I am facing issues and unable to access the values of Name,Email,Phone in the screen flow. I think I am making some mistake in the below script. However the HTML file output is getting displayed on the screen without issues.
I created the LwC component with the above script, placed the LwC component on the screen, also another display text which I default to the Name,Phone,Email values sent to Salesforce screen flow but cannot see those in Salesforce

**html file:**

```
<template>
    <div class="acc-container">
        <lightning-record-view-form record-id={lrecordId} object-api-name={objName}>
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Name"></lightning-output-field>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="MobilePhone"></lightning-output-field>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Email"></lightning-output-field>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning-record-view-form>
    </div>
</template>
```

**js file**:

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire } from 'lwc';

import {FlowAttributeChangeEvent} from 'lightning/flowSupport';

import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";

import NAME_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/User.Name";
import PHONE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/User.MobilePhone";
import EMAIL_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/User.Email";

const fields = [NAME_FIELD, PHONE_FIELD, EMAIL_FIELD];

 
export default class RecordIdExampleLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api lrecordId = "";
    @api objName = "";
    @api Name;
    @api Phone;
    @api Email;

@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: "$lrecordId",
    fields
  })
  user;
  
renderedCallback() {
    console.log(this.user.data);
  }
 

get name() {
   // return getFieldValue(this.user.data, NAME_FIELD);
    const Name = getFieldValue(this.user.data, NAME_FIELD);
  }
  
  get phone() {
  //  return getFieldValue(this.user.data, PHONE_FIELD);
    const Phone = getFieldValue(this.user.data, PHONE_FIELD);
  }

  get email() {
  //  return getFieldValue(this.user.data, EMAIL_FIELD);
    const Email = getFieldValue(this.user.data, EMAIL_FIELD);
  }
  

  handleChange(evt) {
    console.log("Current value of the input: " + evt.target.value);
      this.lrecordId = evt.target.lrecordId;
      this.Name = evt.target.Name
      this.Phone = evt.target.Phone
      this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('lrecordId', this.lrecordId));
      this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('Name', this.Name));
      this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('Phone', this.Phone));
  }
  
  
  }
```

**Meta-xml file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property label="record Id" name="lrecordId"  type="String"/>
            <property label="object Name" name="objName" type="String"/>
            <property label="Internal User Name" name="Name" type="String" role="outputOnly"/>
            <property label="Internal User Phone" name="Phone" type="String" role="outputOnly"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```